# Epistemological Basis of Mathematics Debate

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, foundations-of-mathematics

In the following link: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/ in the last paragraph in Section 1, there is mention of the "lack of epistemological and ontological basis for Mathematics."

Apparently this was a debate between Hilbert and his contemporaries in the early 20th century - what exactly was the debate on? I can't seem to find any content on the topic...

Comment: See [Ferreiros, The Crisis in the Foundations of Mathematics](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8dbf/6c62e3973b4e355efb6058ee91e8b25b3da7.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debate is what is commonly referred to as the Foundational Crisis of the early XX century (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_mathematics#Foundational_crisis). A well-known example of one of the issues from which this crisis stemmed is Russel's paradox in Frege's foundations for mathematics.

Hilbert's position on this is well explained in https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hilbert-program/. Other relevant actors in the debate are Hermann Weyl, Henri Poincaré, Gerhard Gentzen.